# Neo4j - Filter nodes by relationship attribute lists

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Lets say I have collections (`Collection`) that have things (`Thing`) attached to them. These collections can have sub collections which contain a subset of the parent collection. There is a `[:FILTERS]` relationship between parent and the sub collection that contain attribute lists by which the `Thing`s should be filtered. The attributes key are the same as the key on the `Thing`, and the values for the key on the relationship is all the values are accepted on the `Thing`. If the relationship does not have any attributes, all `Thing`s should "shared" between the collections.

The problem that I'm having a hard time solving is how to filter the things by the attributes on the relationship.

Here is what the graph could look like:
[Graph view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwJUL.png)
[image]

and here is the Cypher code for creating said graph:

```
// Collections
CREATE
(C1:Collection {name: 'C1'})-[:FILTERS {type: ['image']}]->(C1_img:Collection {name:'C1_img'}),
(C1_img)-[:FILTERS {user: ['john']}]->(C1_user_img:Collection {name:'C1_user_img'}),

(C2:Collection {name: 'C2'})-[:FILTERS {type: ['image']}]->(C2_img:Collection {name:'C2_img'}),
(C2_img)-[:FILTERS]->(C1)

// C1 Things
CREATE
(C1I1:Thing {id:1, title:"C1 Thing 1", type:'image', user:'john'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(C1),
(C1I2:Thing {id:1, title:"C1 Thing 2", type:'image'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(C1)

// C2 Things
CREATE
(C2I1:Thing {id:1, title:"C2 Thing 1", type:'image'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(C2),
(C2I2:Thing {id:1, title:"C2 Thing 2", type:'image', user:'john'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(C2);
```

Lets say I want to get `Thing`s that should be in `C1_user_img`. That would be all `Thing`s with the type `image` and the user `john`.

```
C1_img -> C1_user_img filters on user=john,
C1->C1_img filters on type=image,
C2_img -> C1 has no filter,
C2 -> C2_img filters on type=images
```

In other words, the `Thing`s C1I1 and C2I2 should be in the C1_user_img collection.

Hopefully this explains my problem.

I've just started using Neo4j and everything is still fairly new for me. I have tried a lot of different approaches to this already but have yet to find something that works.

I can't just create one list of filters and filter all things by that, but I need to filter things for each collection node as the filters might vary by collections.

For instance, if I try:

```
MATCH (start_node:Collection {name: 'C1_user_img'})<-[thing_filters:FILTERS*]-(collections:Collection)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t:Thing)
RETURN thing_filters:FILTERS, t
```

I get back something that I probably could work with; each `Thing` with what it should be filtered by. And then comes the big problem, how to match these values to the values of the `Thing` node. I guess something like all() could be used here, but since all of this is fairly new I haven't figured that out yet.

It might be that this is just too complex to handle in Cypher and some parts needs to be done in code, but it would be nice if it could be done with just a query.

**EDIT**

Since the example that I gave might have been a bit too simple, and my explanation might have been a bit lacking I'm adding a bit more advanced example.

Lets say that you have multiple filters in one `FILTERS` relationship, then all the filters should be taken into consideration. Also, as the filters are lists, as in `{user:['john', 'tom']}`, all values in the list should be accepted. In this case, `Thing`s with the user 'john' *or* 'tom'.

Here is a couple of additional nodes for testing:

```
MATCH (C2:Collection {name:'C2'}), (C1_img:Collection {name:'C1_img'})
CREATE
(C2I3:Thing {id:12, title:"C2 Thing 3", type:'image', user:'john', extra:'foo'}),
(C1_user_extra_img:Collection {name:'C1_user_extra_img'})
CREATE
(C2I3)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(C2),
(C1_img)-[:FILTERS {user: ['john'], extra: ['foo']}]->(C1_user_extra_img)
return C1_user_extra_img, C2I3
```

Now when getting all `Thing`s for `C1_user_extra_img`, would require filtering on both `user` and `extra`. One could also add a `Thing` node with the user 'tom' and then relationship filter on both 'john' and 'tom' and that should return all things that has either the user 'john' or 'tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an interesting one. I've found a solution - maybe someone else comes up with a more elegant one:

```
MATCH (start_node:Collection {name: 'C1_user_img'})<-[thing_filters:FILTERS*]-(collections:Collection)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t:Thing)
WITH t, 
reduce(acc=[], x in thing_filters | acc + keys(x)) AS keys,
reduce(acc=[], x in thing_filters | acc + reduce(b=[], y in keys(x) | x[y]))     AS values
WHERE all(x in range(0,size(keys)-1) WHERE t[keys[x]] = values[x])
RETURN t
```

After matching the path we build a collection for all property keys and property values along the relationships of that path (`keys`, `values`).

Using the `all` predicate we make sure that all elements of `keys` and `values` are set as properties on `t`.

### update

If the property values on the relationships are arrays and the condition is that the respective property value on a thing needs to be in that list a small modification to the existing cypher statement is necessary:

```
MATCH (start_node:Collection {name: 'C1_user_img'})<-[thing_filters:FILTERS*]-(collections:Collection)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t:Thing)
WITH t, 
   reduce(acc=[], x in thing_filters | acc + keys(x)) AS keys,
   reduce(acc=[], x in thing_filters | acc + reduce(b=[], y in keys(x) | [x[y]])) AS values
WHERE all(x in range(0,size(keys)-1) WHERE t[keys[x]] in (values[x]) )
RETURN t
```

By introduction square brackets in the `reduce` for `values` we build up an array of arrays that gets evaluated in the `WHERE`'s all predicate.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this already helps a lot when learning about Cypher. 
It does work when having a single value in the list of filters for one key. Say users: ['john'], but having multiple ones, such as users: ['john', 'tom'] does not work as `keys` and `values` does not have the same length then. The same problem occurs when giving a relationship more than one "filter", for instance {user: ['john'], extra: ['foo']}.

I've updated my question to include a bit more advanced example.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer as it does answer many parts of the question. It still lacks the ability to take multiple filters in one relationship into consideration but the query you provided is still a great starting point for me. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, it seems like the only thing missing from your solution is taking into account that a relationship can have multiple filters. Or you are actually half way there already, but there is a `b +` missing infront of `[x[y]]`. So the second reduce should be `reduce(acc=[], x in thing_filters | acc + reduce(b=[], y in keys(x) | b +[x[y]])) AS values` . Great! Now I know it can be done :)